# (SP List) How to wrap a text in the format view?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

What I'm trying to do is achieve making my own header and hiding the original header so that the users can't change the setting.

To accomplish this, I found that I can change the "Format View".

```
 {
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
   "hideColumnHeader": true,

   "rowFormatter": {
     "elmType": "div",
     "style": {
       "display": "flex",
       "flex-direction": "column",
       "align-items": "flex-start"
     },
     "children": [
       {
         "elmType": "div",
         "attributes": {
           "class": "ms-fontColor-black"
         },
         "style": {
           "display": "=if(@rowIndex == 0, 'flex', 'none')",
           "font-weight": "bold",
           "font-size": "18px",
           "width": "100%",
           "padding": "4px"
         },
         "children": [
           {
             "elmType": "div",
             "txtContent": "Title",
             "style": {
               "width": "80px"
             }
           }
         ]
       },
       {
         "elmType": "div",
         "attributes": {
           "class": "sp-row-listpadding"
         },
         "children": [
           {
             "elmType": "div",
             "style": {
               "text-align": "left"
             },
             "children": [
               {
                 "elmType": "div",
                 "style": {
                   "float": "left",
                   "width": "80px",
                   "font-size": "1.2em",
                   "margin-left": "2px"
                 },
                 "attributes": {
                   "class": "sp-row-title"
                 },
                 "txtContent": "[$Title]"
               }
             ]
           }
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
 }
```

The code above allows me to make my own heading and display the corresponding data, and I just wrote the code for one column. The problem I have is, when I display the data, and when the data is greater than width of 80px (as written in the code), it doesn't wrap and keeps on going down. I tried many methods but they all don't seem to work.

Could someone tell me how to wrap this text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `"white-space": "break-spaces"` to wrap the text. Try using JSON like:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
    "hideColumnHeader": true,
    "rowFormatter": {
        "elmType": "div",
        "style": {
            "display": "flex",
            "flex-direction": "column",
            "align-items": "flex-start"
        },
        "children": [
            {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                    "class": "ms-fontColor-black"
                },
                "style": {
                    "display": "=if(@rowIndex == 0, 'flex', 'none')",
                    "font-weight": "bold",
                    "font-size": "18px",
                    "width": "100%",
                    "padding": "4px"
                },
                "children": [
                    {
                        "elmType": "div",
                        "txtContent": "Title",
                        "style": {
                            "width": "80px",
                            "white-space": "break-spaces"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                    "class": "sp-row-listpadding"
                },
                "children": [
                    {
                        "elmType": "div",
                        "style": {
                            "text-align": "left"
                        },
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "elmType": "div",
                                "style": {
                                    "float": "left",
                                    "width": "80px",
                                    "white-space": "break-spaces",
                                    "font-size": "1.2em",
                                    "margin-left": "2px"
                                },
                                "attributes": {
                                    "class": "sp-row-title"
                                },
                                "txtContent": "[$Title]"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: It works Ganesh, thank you so much. Just one quick question. When I run that, the coding I had on 'Format Columns' disappears. Dyou know how to include that in the coding?

Comment: You added `"white-space": "break-spaces"` in column formatting as well?

Comment: View formats using `rowFormatter` are responsible for drawing the whole thing. If you'd like to use your column formats you can include them in your view format as an element like this `{"columnFormatterReference": "[$InternalNameOfColumn]"}`